# Trigger Div id by button instead a href

Tags: php

I want to know if it's possible to trigger a DIV using a button instead of a href

example
this is the div

```
                                     <div id="ver" class="modal-block modal-block-primary mfp-hide">
                                    <section class="panel">
                                        <header class="panel-heading">
                                            <h2 class="panel-title">Registration Form</h2>
                                        </header>
                                        <form class="form-horizontal mb-lg" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
                                        <div class="panel-body">

                                                <div class="form-group mt-lg">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Name</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your name..." required/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Email</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your email..." required/>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">URL</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <input type="url" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Type an URL..." />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="col-sm-3 control-label">Comment</label>
                                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                                        <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your comment..." required></textarea>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <footer class="panel-footer">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                                                    <input type="submit" name="ola" value="Submit">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-default modal-dismiss">Cancel</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </footer>
                                        </form>
                                    </section>
                                </div>
```

This is how href works to trigger it:

```
<a class="modal-with-form btn btn-default" href="#ver">Open Form</a>
```

There is any possibility?
I need a button because i need to return a value
I tried to do this :

```
 <a class="modal-with-form btn btn-default" href="#ver?id=$ausenciaid">Open Form</a>
```

but it didn't worked!

Thanks

Comment: Hello, welcome to stack overflow pt. You should translate your question to Portuguese, since this is stack overflow pt (Portuguese)

Comment: I didn't understand very well. Do you want show the div "#ver" with a button inside form ?